# Rank of Differential at penetration point

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface. Suppose the straight line span$(e_3)$ penetrates $S$ at $p$. Let $(U,F,V)$ be a local parametrisation of $S$ around $p$.

How can we show that differential $D_uF$ restricted to the first two rows and columns has rank 2?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show some effort here.

Comment: I don't know where to start. The claim seems obvious, as the only way $D_uF$ without the 3rd row does not have rank 2 is if $p$ is a tangent point to span$(e_3)$. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: $D_uF$ has only two columns to start with. I agree that the hypothesis says that $e_3$ is not tangent, but could the $e_1e_2$-plane contain the normal to the surface? If it can't, then it projects isomorphically on the tangent plane.

Comment: Since span$(e_3)\perp$ span$(e_1,e_2)$, if $N_p\subset$ span$(e_1,e_2)$, then span$(e_3) \perp N_p$. However we also know that $T_pS \perp N_p$, therefore we have span$(e_3)\subset T_pS$, making $p$ a tangent point of $S$ and span$(e_3)$, a contradiction to the assumption that $p$ is a penetration point.

Therefore $N_p$ is not contained in the $e_1e_2$-plane. But why does it project isomorphically onto the tangent plane? And how does it help with determining the rank of $DuF$?

Comment: What is the kernel of projection onto the $e_1e_2$-plane? Remember that the columns of $D_uF$ are a basis for the tangent plane. Finish up now and post an answer :)

Comment: The kernel of projection $\pi$ onto the $e_1e_2$-plane is span$(e_3)$. The projection of the normal $N_p=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ is $\pi(N_p)=(n_1,n_2,0)$. I still can't get it :(. Any other hint please?

Comment: The projection of the tangent plane to the $e_1e_2$-plane is an isomorphism iff the tangent plane does *not* contain the kernel of the projection map iff $e_3$ is not in the tangent plane.

Comment: Now I got it thank you very much.